# asp.net MVC 4 EntityType: EntitySet has no keys defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am a MVC newbie so go easy on me please.

I am getting two errors when I try to add a migration. They are as follows:

EntityType 'Icon' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

EntityType: EntitySet 'Icons' is based on type 'Icon' that has no keys defined.

I am including the Icon inside another model, like so:

```
public class Icon
        {
            public string IconName { get; set; }
            public string IconColor { get; set; }
            public int BackgroundXPos { get; set; }
            public int BackgroundYPos { get; set; }
            public string IconColorHover { get; set; }
            public int BackgroundHoverXPos { get; set; }
            public int BackgroundHoverYPos { get; set; }
        }

public class GalleryThumbnail : CSSBoxModel
    {

        [DisplayName("Thumbnail Image Outline Color")]
        public string ThumbnailImageOutlineColor { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Thumbnail Menu Font")]
        public CSSFont ThumbnailMenuFont { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Thumbnail Icon Color")]
        public Icon ThumbnailIconColor { get; set; }

    }
```

How is this Address class below any different which is working:

```
public class Address
    {
        public String Adress1 { get; set; }
        public String Adress2 { get; set; }
        public String Adress3 { get; set; }
        public String City { get; set; }
        public String County { get; set; }
        public String State { get; set; }
        public String Zip { get; set; }
        public String Country { get; set; }

    }

 [Table("UserProfile")] //Could be PP empolyee, Subscriber or Subscriber's customer
    public class UserProfile
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public bool? Gender { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; } //billing address

        public Address ShipAddress { get; set; }


    }
```

I did not add a key in either my Icon or Address class because I have no intention of storing specific data in my DB. They are merely to be used inside other classes. So wy is one neededing an ID and the other is not?

I have not created public DbSet Icons { get; set; } in my DB Context either.

Also can you tell me what it is called when you use a class inside another ( or instance of class inside a class as in these examples ) ?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the address entity has no key defined it the Entity Framework assumes it's a complex property, and your UserProfile table will be rendered with columns named Addres_Address1, Address_Address2, Address_Address3, Address_City, and so on...

Even though you haven't declared an EntitySetIcons DbSet on your context class, it's still being added implicitly because one of your other classes somewhere has an ICollection or IEnumerable property defined.

More info on Code Conventions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

So, either decorate the collections as NotMapped like @Kamyar said or simply remove the references from any class already declared as a DbSet.

Comment: Thanks Amhed and Kamyar. Neither seems to be exactly on point as I could not find any IEnumerable or ICollection of the Icon object. I was able to solve the issue by decorating the property with [ComplexType]. I read that it was a good idea to decorate any Complex Type this way for a variety of reasons similar to mine as stated in this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use [[NotMapped]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) attribute in [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.aspx) namespace in `EntityFramework.dll`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...

[NotMapped]
public Address Address { get; set; } //billing address

[NotMapped]
public Address ShipAddress { get; set; }
```

Regarding the naming, AFAIK these are called public properties as well.